# C# - create function like ToString()

Tags: c#

I want to create function,
the function name is extend() ,it should after the string,bool,control.like default function ToString()

```
"123".extend();
false.extend();
textbox1.extend();
extend();
```

The extend() function can check the input type

```
if input is string ? ToUpperCase , Substring and Replace the string
if input is bool ? checking the bool 
if input is Control ? check control type , change text,color 
if input is List ? to update global list
```

And get property name to do something

```
string SaveString ="";
SaveString.extend();

if(propertyname(object) =="SaveString"){
}
```

How can i create a function like this ?Thanks

Comment: Please be more descriptive.

Comment: And what exactly is `extend` supposed to do?

Comment: It's... still not clear what it is that you want `extend` to do. Do you want it to get the name of the input variable? Because that's not possible, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)

```
namespace System
{
    public static class ObjectExtension
    {
        public static string Extend(this object input)
        {
            // Do something to input object.
            // For example, you can have different implementation based on its type.

            if (input is string)
            {
            }
            else if (input is bool)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There will be **no** performance penalty while using extension methods on object, because it's compiler feature, see [C# Extension Method for Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901427/c-sharp-extension-method-for-object)

Comment: This is one of the few cases where I choose to use the word "never". You should *never* define an extension method for `object`.

Comment: @Abion47 I partially agree with you because I guess the asker wants the extend function to do different stuff for each type.

Comment: There will be no performance penalty while using extension methods on `object`, because it's compiler feature, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901427/c-sharp-extension-method-for-object

Comment: I honestly can't think of an of when the use of an `object` extension method is justifiable where a utility/factory method or generics wouldn't be a better design choice.

Comment: @Abion47 I know what you mean. It is just a matter of taste though, I also personally wouldn't like to have `Extend()` method showing up everywhere in intellisense. Generics does not really suitable unless OP wants the same return type as input. You can always define every extension methods for each type or whatever, the point is to show how it is being done.

Comment: It's not just a matter of taste, though. If I were to create a library that defined an extension method for `object` and someone used that library, all of a sudden extra methods would appear on every single instance they used. This approach is about as nuclear as one can get, because it affects _everything_. Just because something can be done doesn't mean that it should be done (see `dynamic`). In general, I am also in the camp that every rule can be broken by someone who knows what they are doing, but in this case, it's just objectively bad design.